# IF statements in Solidity not behaving as expected

Tags: solidity

When I fire this function for the first time it seems `revealEnd = now;` fires because the reveal period ends.  Yet `revealCount` does in fact display `'1'`, indicating that we went into BOTH if statements.

The first time through however the first if statement should be false and `revealEnd = now;` should be completely skipped...

Is there something wrong here?

```
function reveal(uint _values, uint _secret)
    onlyAfter(biddingEnd)
    onlyBefore(revealEnd)
{
    //var bid = choices[msg.sender][0]; 

    if (revealCount == 1)
        playerTwoChoice = _values;
        revealCount = 2;
        playerTwoAddress = msg.sender;
        revealEnd = now;

    if (revealCount == 0)
        playerOneChoice = _values;
        revealCount = 1;
        playerOneAddress = msg.sender;
}
```

Comment: you need brackets around the statements after each 'if'.  This isn't python...

Comment: @PaulS Please add it as an answer, because 1) this beta needs more answers (http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-to-gain-more-expertise?cb=1), 2) the question looks like unanswered :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solidity has a syntax sort-of borrowed from Javascript.  This means it uses braces to denote groups of statements, not whitespace like Python.

You can find complete documentation [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Your code should look like this:

```
function reveal(uint _values, uint _secret)
    onlyAfter(biddingEnd)
    onlyBefore(revealEnd)
{
    //var bid = choices[msg.sender][0]; 

    if (revealCount == 1) {
        playerTwoChoice = _values;
        revealCount = 2;
        playerTwoAddress = msg.sender;
        revealEnd = now;
    }
    if (revealCount == 0) {
        playerOneChoice = _values;
        revealCount = 1;
        playerOneAddress = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes was happy to finally see this! Ty

Comment: Note that you may omit braces for single instruction if